# how to exclude classes from pmd rule by regexp

Tags: java, pmd

Is there a way to exclude classes from PMD rule by class name pattern?

I'm looking for sth like:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/coupling.xml/ExcessiveImports">
    <exclude-pattern>.*Test\.class</exclude-pattern>
</rule>
```

I'm aware of violationSuppressXPath approach but I find it too ugly/complex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a rule that'll ignore a specific rule if the class name ends with `DTO`:

```
  <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml/UnusedPrivateField">
    <properties>
      <!--Ignore UnusedPrivateField on classes where the class name ends with DTO-->
      <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration['.*DTO']"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
```

Ref https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1142.

Comment: This answer is not 100% accurate. In my case, it randomly suppressed some other stuff as well.

From the PMD docs: `Note the use of . to refer to the context node. Using // at the start of the expression should be avoided, as it would test all nodes in the file, and suppress more violations than expected.` See [here](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

I fear there is not. You can currently completely ignore files from analysis with `<exclude-pattern>`, but not for a specific rule.

The rationale behind this, is that when enforcing a ruleset on your codebase, you should attempt to be as consistent as possible. In doing so, few exceptions are considered:

- having separate rulesets for test / main code
- allowing to suppress individual cases where the rule may not apply for very specific, yet valid reasons

Your example seems to point in the direction of the first scenario. If you want a more relaxed set of rules for test classes, you should create a separate configuration and have PMD run two separate analysis.

This is however outside the scope of PMD itself, but on how you run it. On Gradle / Ant / CLI this is very straightforward to achieve. On Maven unfortunately it's currently unsupported (a feature request can be found and voted [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPMD-242?jql=project%20%3D%20MPMD))

If you feel you have another scenario, not covered by the previous two, that should be taken into consideration, please post a feature request on https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues

Comment: I've been searching around for a while and this is the first clear explanation that understands the pain point of wanting to have different rulesets for `main` and `test` while also explaining that Maven doesn't support this scenario right now. FWIW, I find the rationale for the current behavior of `exclude-pattern` to be an overly prescriptive stance by the PMD plugin. Good defaults are a good thing, but this level of inflexibility reduces the power of the tool with no compensatory gain.